# What is the name for the pattern of requiring the user to enter their password again to access high value profile information (billing, email)?

Tags: password

Many sites leave the user logged in for typical tasks but require the password to be entered again for certain high-value screens if it's been too long since the user authenticated with username and password. What's the name of this pattern?

Specific examples: Amazon, which lets you browse and add to a cart with an old session but requires a password to check out, or Github, which lets you open tickets, comment on PRs, and commit code but requires a password to see your API keys if you've had a session open a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known as **[re-authentication](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet#Require_Re-authentication_for_Sensitive_Features)**.

You can have this trigger by a **Session Timeout**, which kicks the user out of being able to view any page (or initiate certain actions) after a specified amount of idle time.